# HTML form formatting (form too wide)

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a table with some forms and buttons in the cells, but there is too much space between the buttons. It looks like the form is too wide, but I can't figure out why. Here is the problem on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2st7f6j/), and a screenshot below.

[image]

My forms are in a cell, like this:

```
<td>
  <form>
    <button>
      test
    </button>
  </form>
</td>
```

What kind of CSS magic do I need to narrow the gap between the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem depends kind of on what you're ultimately trying to accomplish.

Is there too much space between the buttons OR are the buttons too small OR both?

If you add:

```
button {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then you'll have much less space between them - but the button now fills its respective space on the table. If you have this table the width of a large screen, then the buttons will be very large and odd looking.

If you want them to be equally spaced - then you could add this instead of the above:

```
button {
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
}
```

This will center the button directly in its own respective column although it won't reduce the space between them.

Another approach would be to reduce the padding that comes default on the `<td>` element.

```
td {
    padding-left: 0.25rem;
    padding-right: 0.25rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the forms in the same `td` and then style them with `inline-block` as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/0sf8vnzL/

Or you can do something like this to change the tables width: `table {width: 50%;}`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you could add this CSS that will prevent the columns expanding / contracting based on the content entered into them and effectively equally distribute the total width among the columns.

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Here's a fiddle link :

https://jsfiddle.net/o2st7f6j/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  following CSS. Especially `width: auto;` for the table makes your table * not*  span the whole container width anymore. The rest of the settings is to avoid margins, paddings etc. The `padding: 2px;` od `td` is just to keep some distance between the buttons - you can set it any way you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/L847penr/

```css
table {
  width: auto;
}

form {
  margin: 0px;
}

td {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

td:first-child,
td:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

button {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th colspan="4">Buttons</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>hello</td>
    <td>hello</td>
    <td>
      <form>
        <button>test</button>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form>
        <button>test</button>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form>
        <button>test</button>
      </form>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form>
        <button>test</button>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd test button use  style="margin-left: -60px;" and if that only works a little increase the negative amount of pixels.